# Angular momentum-torque relationship in a rotating frame?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rotation

I have read that $$\vec\tau=\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec L}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
holds true whenever the origin is not accelerating. But I cannot see why this holds true for a rotating frame of reference (such as one that rotates with the body), please can anyone explain why this is so? Also if possible please could you provide a source?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by origin accelerating?

Comment: @StanShunpike Simply that if $\vec r_0$ is the position vector of the origin of the given coordinate system with respect to another inertial frame of reference then $\ddot{\vec r} \ne 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you calculate $\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{L}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ of a particle of mass, m, having a linear momentum of $\vec{\mathrm{p}}$ in an inertial frame via a rotating frame or rotating body where the acceleration is directed towards the origin, you get this:$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{L}_{inertial}}{\mathrm{d}t}=m\bigg(\vec{r}\times\frac{\mathrm{d^2}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\bigg)+\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{L}_{rotational}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
or$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{L}_{rotational}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{L}_{inertial}}{\mathrm{d}t}-m\bigg(\vec{r}\times\frac{\mathrm{d^2}\vec{r}}{\mathrm{d}t^2}\bigg)$$
In the second term of the right hand side, $\vec{r}$ is the position vector of the rotating frame of reference with respect to the inertial frame. $\vec{r}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d^2\vec{r}}}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$ are opposite to each other so their cross product is zero and the first term remains. In other accelerating reference frames, this second term doesn't vanish.